# Как реализовать такой элемент UI в Android

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать такой элемент UI в Android? ( интересует именно белое и красное View) Я сначала подумала, что можно сделать, как `Navigation Drawer`(для белого меню) , но тут получается, что верхняя View (красная) при свайпе должна съезжать вправо и снизу должно уже быть белое меню.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У большинства библиотек для iOS такое поведение. Под андроид можете взять, к примеру, готовое решение и переделать: [по скринам вроде похоже](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/ActionsContentView). Ну или другую найти.

Если сами хотите сделать, подсказка - в основе у них FrameLayout.

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите, а в IOS это стандартный элемент?

Comment: @Lucky_girl , нет